# Produce a string of html code from mpld3 on a Django view

Tags: python, django, d3.js, matplotlib

I'm looking at the possibility of sending a matplotlib figure which is produced at a Django view. 
I've managed so far to use the mpld3.show() function form a view, but it starts it's own server, and all I want is a string describing the plot, which I can further send in my response.
Simply speaking:

Create matplotlib figure -> convert to a string of html code (which I ofc will just store in a variable).

I'm halfway on the documentation and might be closing into something (see http://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.fig_to_html, but I would appreciate if someone has some working, simple example that could be shared here. Thanks.

ANSWER: It was quite easy actually:

http://pastebin.com/QLN4gqSD

Comment: Thanks, it was useful for me! Maybe you can make this as an answer ?

Comment: Well yes, it's actually the right answer ^^